# How to add a series to an existing dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I want to add the 'new' Series to the 'mydata' Dataframe
[THE CODE IS THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efazk.jpg)

Comment: Use `df['new'] = k.astype(int)`

Comment: Or `df['new'] = new`

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.